# Как запустить скрипт python | в новой консоли. При этом скрыв саму консоль?

Tags: python, gui, консоль, powershell

**Как запустить скрипт python | в новой консоли. При этом скрыв саму консоль?**

У меня программу с `gui`. но эту программу я запускаю из другой. и чтобы не замораживать цикл я решил создавать новое окно консооли при помощи:

```
os.system("start python main.py")
```

Но я хотел бы скрыть саму консоль. Сделать её невидимой. чтоб скрипт при этом работал.

Comment: Если задача в «не замораживать цикл», то, может, просто потоки используйте?

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'main.py'])
```

и через [poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) проверяй периодически завершился ли процесс

```
status = p.poll()
if status is None:
    print('running')
elif status == 0:
    print('exit success')
elif status > 0:
    print('exit error')
elif status < 0:
    print('exit killed')
```

Прочитать вывод можно через [пайпы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Comment: этот скрирпт запустится в той же консоли

Comment: он запустится без консоли

Comment: спасибо. Но вопрос ещё 1. как ппроверить была ли ошибка в subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

**В общем ответ очень простой.**

**Есть 2 типа запуска скрипта python.** это python и pythonw т.е. если написать команду таким образом:

> `os.system("start pythonw files/browser.py")`

*Программа подавит запуск консоли. Это удобно так как можно запускать цикл в цикличной программе. Занеся сам цикл в отдельный файл и запуская его из новой консоли.*

Comment: Да, но будьте готовы к подводным камням. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe#:~:text=To%20summarize%20and%20complement%20the%20existing%20answers%3A